# how to set a recordtype when creating a Lead record in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I have hardcoded the record ID in javascript but it is giving me an error.

```
Error: {"status":400,"body":{"message":"Field recordTypeId does not exist.","statusCode":400,"errorCode":"POST_BODY_PARSE_ERROR"},"headers":{},"ok":false,"statusText":"Bad Request","errorType":"fetchResponse"}
```

```
 const fields = this.leadRecord;
    fields.recordTypeId="0128000000037AIAAY";
```

Any inputs?

Comment: Can you provide more information? This is incomplete information. What are you using to get lead records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using **RecordTypeId** instead of **recordTypeId**. Javascript is case sensitive language and it will treat RecordTypeId and recordTypeId both as different variable, and hence it is not recognizing **recordTypeId**  as salesforce recordtypeId variable instead treating it as a simple local variable.

Comment: I tired both and it did not work

Comment: can you put your code snippet here and show how it actually looks?

Comment: fields.RecordTypeId="0128000000047AIAAY";

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing it on submit method you can also pass record-type-id attribute in record form as well.

Comment: can you elaborate how to do in the record form? and I was able to assign values for other fields but not this one why?

Comment: Just like you do object-api-name similarly you can do for **record-type-id={recordtypeid} ** as well in record type edit form in html.

Comment: I did not use lightning-record-edit-form to do that